# Calculating the load time of page elements using Rcurl? (R)

Tags: optimization, r, curl, rcurl

I started playing with the idea of testing a webpage load time using R.  I have devised a tiny R code to do so:

```
page.load.time <- function(theURL, N = 10, wait_time = 0.05)
{
    require(RCurl)
    require(XML)
    TIME <- numeric(N)
    for(i in seq_len(N))
    {
        Sys.sleep(wait_time)
        TIME[i] <- system.time(webpage <- getURL(theURL, header=FALSE, 
                                                 verbose=TRUE) )[3]
    }
    return(TIME)
}
```

And would welcome your help in several ways:

1. Is it possible to do the same, but to also know which parts of the page took what parts to load? (something like Yahoo's [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/))
2. I sometime run into the following error -

> Error in curlPerform(curl = curl,
>   .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding) :
>   Failure when receiving data from the
>   peer Timing stopped at: 0.03 0 43.72

Any suggestions on what is causing this and how to catch such errors and discard them?

Can you think of ways to improve the above function?

**Update**: I redid the function.  It is now painfully slow...

```
one.page.load.time <- function(theURL, HTML = T, JavaScript = T, Images = T, CSS = T)   
{
    require(RCurl)
    require(XML)
    TIME <- NULL


    if(HTML) TIME["HTML"] <- system.time(doc <- htmlParse(theURL))[3]
    if(JavaScript) {
        theJS <- xpathSApply(doc, "//script/@src")  # find all JavaScript files
        TIME["JavaScript"] <- system.time(getBinaryURL(theJS))[3]
    } else ( TIME["JavaScript"] <- NA)
    if(Images) {
        theIMG <- xpathSApply(doc, "//img/@src")    # find all image files
        TIME["Images"] <- system.time(getBinaryURL(theIMG))[3]
    } else ( TIME["Images"] <- NA)
    if(CSS) {
        theCSS <- xpathSApply(doc, "//link/@href")  # find all "link" types
        ss_CSS <- str_detect(tolower(theCSS), ".css")   # find the CSS in them
        theCSS <- theCSS[ss_CSS]
        TIME["CSS"] <- system.time(getBinaryURL(theCSS))[3]
    } else ( TIME["CSS"] <- NA)

    return(TIME)
}



page.load.time <- function(theURL, N = 3, wait_time = 0.05,...)
{
    require(RCurl)
    require(XML)
    TIME <- vector(length = N, "list")
    for(i in seq_len(N))
    {
        Sys.sleep(wait_time)
        TIME[[i]] <- one.page.load.time(theURL,...)
    }
    require(plyr)
    TIME <- data.frame(URL = theURL, ldply(TIME, function(x) {x}))
    return(TIME)
}

a <- page.load.time("http://www.r-bloggers.com/", 2)
a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your getURL call will only do one request and get the source HTML for the web page. It won't get the CSS or Javascript or other elements. If this is what you mean by 'parts' of the web page then you'll have to scrape the source HTML for those parts (in SCRIPT tags, or css references etc) and getURL them separately with timing.

Comment: Thanks, any suggestions on how to do this will be helpful :)

Comment: Depends how complex you want it. Some web pages will be grabbing stuff using ajax, and that means running Javascript...

Comment: mmm... Do you know if it is even possible to run Javascript using R?

Comment: Of course its possible. First write a Javascript parser, build a syntax tree, then.. Oh I never said it was easy. Short answer: no. Medium answer: you might be able to leverage Firefox or one of the other JS implementations. Why do you need to do all this in R anyway?

Comment: :)  I wish to estimate the loading time of a page.  In order to do that I would like to reload a page several times to give a good estimate of that page loading time.  My native language is R, so that is the first place I seek for help.  I'll think of more ways to ask this and come again :)

Comment: Hi S_M, I updated the function to also download images,CSS,JavaScript.  It is now painfully slow.  Any further suggestions will be most welcomed.

Comment: Slow where? Is the sum of the reported page load times a lot lot less than the time it takes to load all the bits? If so, then something in your code is slow. If not, then the pages are taking that long to load. Most browsers will load things in parallel, and cache them, leading to big big wins. Give us some numbers!

Comment: Thanks for asking - Simply run the last two lines that I've added in the updated code section, and see for yourself. (slow as in 5-20 seconds for loading javascript/images - sometimes it seems to get "stuck")

Comment: In addition to needing to mimic caching, parallel loading, etc., the other problem you're going to run in to is that downloading isn't the entirety of what makes a page fast/slow - there's also rendering in the browser, which can be a not insignificant portion of this. Try using something that does this for you - http://tools.pingdom.com/ is my favorite, but there are others. I think you'll find it a lot easier to scrape the results from one of these vs. trying to do your own testing engine.

Comment: That's an interesting idea Noah.  Although i seem to be having difficulties with scraping pingdom test results... (I'll have a look at it again, thanks for the tip)

Comment: "My native language is R" - wow, your English is pretty good too! :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Spidermonkey from Omegahat could work.
http://www.omegahat.org/SpiderMonkey/

Comment: Thanks Greg, I suspect I won't go into this in the near future, but this is good to know.